# Parse RelativeLayout, Set Content, And Add It To A LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

Ok... here's my situation.

I have a carousel of images in a `HorizontalScrollView` - which contains a `LinearLayout` - in my `Activity`, like so:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/carousel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
    />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have a `TypedArray`, loop through it, and on each run, set these images programatically, add a ClickListener and a Tag, and add this `ImageView` to the `LinearLayout` (set in my `Activity` Layout), like so:

```
    // Get the array
    final TypedArray carouselArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.carousel_array);

    // Populate the Carousel with item
    for (int i = 0 ; i < carouselArray.length() ; ++i) {

    // Image Item               
    ImageView outerImage;

        // Set the image view resource
        if(i == 0) {
            outerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.toy_filter_clear);
        }
        else {
            outerImage.setImageResource(carouselArray.getResourceId(i, -1));
        }

        // Set Touch Listener
        outerImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
        final String prepend = "CAROUSEL_";
        final String index = String.valueOf(i);
        final String tag = prepend.concat(index);
        outerImage.setTag(tag);

        /// Add image view to the Carousel container
        mCarouselContainer.addView(outerImage);

    }
```

But now, I just found out that I have to programatically add a second image to sit inside/on top of the first image at particular coordinates (damn you UI ppl!). I need these to be considered the same image/view essentially, so need to pack them together inside of a layout, I am assuming. So I have made a layout file, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/carousel_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carousel_outer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/toy_filter_normal" 
        />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carousel_inner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/carousel_outer"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/carousel_outer"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb_nofilter" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This has the proper positioning, and the default images set on it. So what I want to be able to do is to reach into the Layout file, grab the ImageViews by their ID, overwrite the image if necessary, and then add that `RelativeLayout` to my `LinearLayout` at the end of my loop... sounds easy enough, right ?

My first attempt was to do it like this :

```
        RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.carousel_item);
        ImageView outerImage = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.carousel_outer);
        ImageView innerImage = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.carousel_inner);
```

... but that gives me a NullPointer on the ImageView...So then I tried to inflate the RelativeLayout first, like this:

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carousel_item_layout, null);
        ImageView outerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.carousel_outer);
        ImageView innerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.carousel_inner);
```

This gets rid of the NPE's, and (apparently) let's the images be set properly like so:

```
            if(i == 0) {
                outerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.toy_filter_clear);
                innerImage.setImageResource(0);
            }
            else {
                outerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.toy_filter_normal);                  
                innerImage.setImageResource(carouselArray.getResourceId(i, -1));
            }
```

but when I try to add the outerImage ImageView back to the LinearLayout, I get an NPE there:

```
mCarouselContainer.addView(outerImage);
```

More to the point, I don't want to add ONLY the one ImageView to the `LinearLayout/HorizontalScrollView` - I want to somehow pack the resulting images back into the RelativeLayout and add the whole thing back into my `LinearLayout`... but, it is worth mentioning, that this also gives me an NPE.

What is a guy to do ? Any thoughts appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Wow, thanks SO Code Monkey!

I managed to fix this with a one line fix, by adding the inflated View to the LinearLayout instead of the ImageView or the RelativeLayout (which wasn't doing anything), like so:

```
mCarouselContainer.addView(view);
```

Don't know why I hadn't tried that before, but I was unclear on whether as it's children were being updated if it would reflect the parent, so to speak... now I know it was.

I'm gonna keep the question up, as I think it's helpful... ?